Constraint linear system of equations
I have a linear system of equations of the form
\begin{equation}
    x_i = x_{i-1}+\tanh(i/(N+1)),\quad i=1,...,N+1
\end{equation}
And I intend to find both $x$ and $N$ while satisfying the following constraints
\begin{align}
    x_{N+1}=a\\
    x_1=1
\end{align}
I can programmatically test increasing numbers of $N$ until $x_{N+1}>a$ by building from $i=2$ upwards. This seems rather inefficient. Is there a way to pose this as an optimization problem with constraints so that I can converge to the appropriate value of $N$? The fact that I have two unknown variables ($x_i$ and $N$) is confusing me.

One way to get a set of bounds on $N$ is to notice that this resembles a Riemann sum. In particular, if we partition the interval $t \in [0, 1]$ with even spacing so that $t_i = \frac{i}{N+1}$ for $i = 0, \ldots, N+1$, then the lower and upper Riemann sums of $f(t) = \tanh(t)$ on the interval are
$$\begin{eqnarray} S_L & = & \sum_{i = 0}^N f(t_i) \Delta t_i \\
& = & \frac{1}{N+1} \sum_{i = 0}^N \tanh \left(\frac{i}{N+1}\right) \\
& = & \frac{1}{N+1} \sum_{i = 1}^N \tanh \left(\frac{i}{N+1}\right) \\
& = & \frac{1}{N+1} \left(x_{N+1} - 1 - \tanh 1 \right) \\
S_U & = & \frac{1}{N+1} \sum_{i = 1}^{N+1} \tanh \left(\frac{i}{N+1}\right) \\
& = & \frac{1}{N+1} \left(x_{N+1} - 1 \right)\end{eqnarray}$$
And since these provide lower and upper bounds for the integral, that gives us
$$ \frac{1}{N+1} \left(x_{N+1} - 1 - \tanh 1\right) \leq \int_0^1 \tanh(t) dt \leq \frac{1}{N+1} \left(x_{N+1} - 1\right)$$
We can evaluate the integral in the middle and apply the constraint $x_{N+1} = a$ to get
$$ \frac{a - 1 - \tanh 1}{\ln \cosh 1} - 1 \leq N \leq \frac{a - 1}{\ln \cosh 1} - 1 $$
or alternatively,
$$(N+1) \ln \cosh 1 + 1 \leq a \leq (N+1) \ln \cosh 1 + 1 + \tanh 1$$
which gives a nice linear bounding relationship between $a$ and $N$.
(Note that the chance of an error in my calculations is high, so I recommend working through it yourself as well.)

By its definition, this can only ever hit discrete values of $a$. This will give an approximation of what those values are, at best.

I would like to convince you that programmatically test numbers is not that inefficient.
You can rely on the fact that $\forall a,b \geq 0, \tanh(a) + \tanh(b) = \frac{e^{a}-e^{-a}}{e^{a}+e^{-a}}+\frac{e^{b}-e^{-b}}{e^{b}+e^{-b}}=\frac{(e^{a}-e^{-a})(e^{b}+e^{-b})+(e^{b}-e^{-b})(e^{a}+e^{-a})}{(e^{a}+e^{-a})(e^{b}+e^{-b})}=\frac{2(e^{a+b}-e^{-(a+b)})}{(e^{a+b}+e^{-(a+b)})+e^{a-b}+e^{b-a}} \geq \tanh(a+b).$
Then $X_{N+1} \geq \tanh(1+\sum_{i=2}^{N+1}\frac{i}{N+1}) = \tanh(2-\frac{1}{N+1}).$
If $a\leq 1,$ you should test $N$ in a neighborhood of $N_0$, in which $\tanh(2-\frac{1}{N_0+1})=a$, this is better than testing from $2$.
If $a>1,$ you could test an initial value $N'$ which results in $a'$. If $a' > a$, you reduce $N'$. Otherwise, you increase $N'$, until the algorithm converges. Use Polynomial Interpolation to calculate the appropriate change.

Thanks for the insight!
